# Подключение скрипта в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Могу спокойно подключить js на всех страницах в WordPress.

```
wp_enqueue_script('datahelp', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/datahelp.js', array(), false, true);
```

Этот код хорошо работает и скрипт работает.

Но мне нужно это скрипт подключить только на странице с шаблоном single-product.php

Пытаюсь просто зарегистрировать скрипт в functions.php

```
wp_register_script('datahelp', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/datahelp.js', array(), false, true);
```

После этого вызываю в шаблоне

```
wp_enqueue_script('datahelp');
```

Не работает.

Пытался сделать в functions.php так

```
add_action( 'mydatahelp','add_datahelp');

function add_datahelp() {
    if (is_page_template('single-product.php')) { 
wp_enqueue_script('datahelp', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/datahelp.js', array(), false, true);
}
}
```

Тоже не работает.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: а что за хук такой - mydatahelp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делайте, как положено, по событию `wp_enqueue_script`, и всё будет работать. В `function.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );

function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    if (is_page_template('single-product.php')) { 
        wp_enqueue_script('datahelp', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/datahelp.js', array(), false, true);
    }
}
```

У вас не работает потому, что вы пытаетесь запустить функцию по несуществующему хуку - он и не срабатывает.

Размещение кода `is_page_template` просто в теле `functions.php` - тоже не годится, потому что в этот момент ещё не определён главный цикл WP, и условные теги (функции типа страницы, шаблона) и т.д. не работают. Проще говоря - там ещё рано. А вот по `wp_enqueue_scripts` - в самый раз.

Comment: Спасибо большое.